# How to handle null values in mvc view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
<li>
   <%=Html.UITemplates().FieldLong().TextBox("OrderRequest.AdditionalParties[0].ContactDetails[0].Address.Line1", "Address", Model.OrderRequest.AdditionalParties[0].Address.Line1)%>
</li>
```

The above line when Address is null throws a null reference exception. I don't know how to handle it as I still want to display view while Address.Line1 should be displayed as empty string.

Comment: What is `Html.UITemplates().FieldLong().TextBox()`? Its not part of MVC

Comment: `Model.OrderRequest.AdditionalParties[0].Address == null ? string.Empty : Model.OrderRequest.AdditionalParties[0].Address.Line1  %>` try this.

Comment: You'll need to null-check every part of that object chain. Just the Address property is taking a risk. It's better to work with smaller models to keep things clean.

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes it's not part of mvc. They are custom html helpers in my project.

Comment: @vendettamit that's what I want. Thanks. Please post it as answer so that I can mark it as correct answer

Comment: @MartijnK not able to change now as I just joined this project and I am only fixing a bug in the  project.I will remember this tip in future thanks!

Comment: The you should show them. If you have written this helper correctly, then all you need is `Html.UITemplates().FieldLong().TextBox("OrderRequest.AdditionalParties[0].ContactDetails[0].Address.Line1")` which will set the value attribute to `value=""` if its null, and no exception will be thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the conditional operator to check the null values on any object. So in your case it would be:

`Model.OrderRequest.AdditionalParties[0].Address == null ? string.Empty : Model.OrderRequest.AdditionalParties[0].Address.Line1 %>`